# Ensure Textbox remain at same position when I update the form

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I am creating an calendar features which takes inputs from a form and based of that I will assign into a dynamic calendar. The problem I'm facing now is that when I update my form the first textbox position does not remain at its original position but goes to the second textbox position.

I tried using ChatGPT for helped but I can't seem to find a way to solve this problem.

```
Dim SVDateValue As String
Dim DPValue As String
Dim SVTimeValue As String
Dim companyValue As String

SVDateValue = sourceSheet.Range("C23").Value
DPValue = sourceSheet.Range("J12").Value
SVTimeValue = sourceSheet.Range("C24").Value
companyValue = sourceSheet.Range("C11").Value & " " & sourceSheet.Range("C12").Value

'Open the DynamicCalendar workbook
Dim calendarWorkbook As Workbook
Set calendarWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\DynamicCalendar.xlsm")

'Get the Values worksheet from the DynamicCalendar workbook
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Set destSheet = calendarWorkbook.Sheets("Values")

If destSheet.ProtectContents Then
        destSheet.Unprotect
End If
' Transfer data to destination workbook
destSheet.Range("B1").Value = SVDateValue  ' Example: Service Date
destSheet.Range("B2").Value = DPValue
destSheet.Range("B3").Value = companyValue
destSheet.Range("B4").Value = SVTimeValue

' Convert SVDateValue to a proper date value
Dim searchDate As Date
searchDate = DateValue(SVDateValue)

' Extract month, year, and day
Dim extractedMonth As String
Dim extractedYear As Integer
Dim extractedDay As Integer
Dim formattedDay As String

extractedMonth = MonthName(Month(searchDate))
extractedYear = Year(searchDate)
extractedDay = Day(searchDate)
'formattedDay = Format(extractedDay, "dd")
formattedDay = Right("0" & extractedDay, 2) ' Format as two-digit day with leading zero

'MsgBox extractedMonth
'MsgBox extractedYear
'MsgBox extractedDay
'MsgBox extractedDay


Dim calendarSheet As Worksheet
Set calendarSheet = calendarWorkbook.Sheets("Calendar")

' Update the month and year cells
calendarSheet.Range("D1").Value = extractedMonth
calendarSheet.Range("G1").Value = extractedYear

' Search for the specific date within the range B:H
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim searchCell As Range
Set searchRange = calendarSheet.Range("B:H")
Set searchCell = searchRange.Find(What:=formattedDay, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
'MsgBox formattedDay 'Formated Date so it is dd

     ' Delete Existing
    Dim shapesToDelete As New Collection ' Collection to hold shapes to be deleted
    'MsgBox dpNumber
    For Each TextBox In calendarSheet.Shapes
        If TextBox.Type = msoTextBox Then ' Check if the shape is a textbox
            Dim lines() As String
            Dim dpValueFromShape As String
            Dim dateFromShape As Date 'Additional
            
    ' Remove error handling for debugging purposes
    ' On Error Resume Next
    lines = Split(TextBox.TextFrame.Characters.Text, vbLf) ' Split the text into lines using vbLf
    ' On Error GoTo 0
    
    If UBound(lines) >= 1 Then ' Ensure there are at least 2 lines (0-based index)
        dpValueFromShape = Trim(lines(1)) ' Second line (index 1) is DPValue, with leading/trailing spaces removed
        dateFromShape = DateValue(lines(0)) ' First line (index 0) is the date
        ' Display the extracted value for debugging
        'MsgBox "Extracted DP Value: " & dpValueFromShape

                If dpValueFromShape = dpNumber Then
                    shapesToDelete.Add TextBox ' Add the shape to the collection for deletion
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next TextBox
        ' Delete shapes from the collection
Dim shapeToDelete As Variant
For Each shapeToDelete In shapesToDelete
    shapeToDelete.Delete
Next shapeToDelete
If Not searchCell Is Nothing Then
Dim targetCell As Range
For Each targetCell In searchRange
    If IsDate(targetCell.Value) Then
        Dim currentDate As Date
        currentDate = DateValue(targetCell.Value)

        ' Compare currentDate with SVDateValue (day and month)
        If Day(currentDate) = Day(searchDate) And Month(currentDate) = Month(searchDate) Then
            ' Set the targetRow and targetColumn based on the current targetCell
            Dim targetRow As Long
            Dim targetColumn As Long
            targetRow = targetCell.Row
            targetColumn = targetCell.Column

            ' Find the existing textbox in the same cell with matching DPValue and SVDateValue
            Dim existingTb As Shape
            For Each existingTb In calendarSheet.Shapes
                If existingTb.Type = msoTextBox Then
                    'Dim lines() As String
                    lines = Split(existingTb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text, vbCrLf)
                    If UBound(lines) >= 1 Then
                        'Dim dpValueFromShape As String
                        dpValueFromShape = Trim(lines(1)) ' Second line (index 1) is DPValue
                        'Dim dateFromShape As Date
                        dateFromShape = DateValue(lines(0)) ' First line (index 0) is the date
                        If dpValueFromShape = dpNumber And dateFromShape = SVDateValue Then
                            ' Update the text content of the existing textbox
                            existingTb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = SVDateValue & vbCrLf & DPValue & vbCrLf & companyValue & vbCrLf & SVTimeValue
                            ' Optionally, update other properties if needed
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next existingTb

            ' If no existing textbox found, create a new one in the correct cell
            If existingTb Is Nothing Then
                ' Calculate the top position for the new textbox (below the existing ones)
                Dim spacing As Double
                spacing = 10 ' Adjust spacing as needed
                Dim originalTextboxHeight As Double
                originalTextboxHeight = 90 ' Fixed height for the original textbox

                ' Count the number of textboxes in the same cell
                Dim textBoxCount As Long
                For Each tb In calendarSheet.Shapes
                    If tb.Type = msoTextBox Then
                        If tb.TopLeftCell.Row = targetRow And tb.TopLeftCell.Column = targetColumn Then
                            textBoxCount = textBoxCount + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next tb

                ' Calculate the top position using the formula: targetCell.Top + TextBox.Height * n + spacing
                Dim topPosition As Double
                topPosition = calendarSheet.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Top + spacing ' Start from the top of the cell

                Dim tbTopPosition As Double
                tbTopPosition = topPosition + originalTextboxHeight * textBoxCount + spacing

                ' Create a new textbox in the correct cell and position
                Set tb = calendarSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                                                          Left:=calendarSheet.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Left, _
                                                          Top:=tbTopPosition, _
                                                          Width:=calendarSheet.Cells(targetRow, targetColumn).Width, _
                                                          Height:=80)
                ' ... Set properties for the TextBox
                tb.Fill.Transparency = 1 ' Fully transparent fill
                tb.Line.Visible = msoFalse ' No border

                ' Set TextBox text to SVDate and company values
                tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = SVDateValue & vbCrLf & DPValue & vbCrLf & companyValue & vbCrLf & SVTimeValue

                ' Change color of SVDateValue text to not filled
                tb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, Len(SVDateValue)).Font.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

                ' Increment the textbox count
                textBoxCount = textBoxCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next targetCell
```

But like sometimes when I update the form for the second and third textbox or subsequent the position is alright but this is not consistent. And the original textbox one when I update it always messes up by going into the second textbox position and not the top position of that cell+spacing.

[image]

Comment: Pretty difficult for us to debug something which is intermittent - you should add some debugging output to your procedure, and/or step through the code and see where it's going off-track.  Also consider splitting that code up to factor out common parts into their own subs/functions: that's too much code for a single method.

Comment: the problem is when im updating my textbox,the textbox position is adding to other textbox position. 
 If dpValueFromShape = dpNumber And dateFromShape = SVDateValue Then
                            ' Update the text content of the existing textbox
                            existingTb.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = SVDateValue & vbCrLf & DPValue & vbCrLf & companyValue & vbCrLf & SVTimeValue
                      
Like the formula it is using the x the number of texbox in that cell which is meant for inserting textbox only. I want the textbox position to be fixed at where it was at.